# Why is light not working in unity 2D mode?

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I manage to add light effects in my game, but I find that light only works in 3D mode. When it comes to 2D, light basically does nothing. From watching some tutorials I learned that to enable lighting in 2D, I have to create stuff like normal maps and materials and do some work with photograph editor software. But I do not know why there is such difference between 2D and 3D in terms of lighting. Could anyone give me any hint about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you that Unity doesn't offer 2D light out of the box, you could instead [develop by your self the system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwyAoE_uMFo) or just use assets like  [2DDL Pro](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/2ddl-pro-2d-dynamic-lights-and-shadows-25933) which is bundled inside the Unity Plus package.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes sense.